# Why does running this Dash app produce a TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror, plotly-dash

I'm getting the following error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 11, in <module>
    app = dash.Dash()
  File "C:\Users\oefel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 268, in __init__

self.server = flask.Flask(name) if server else None
  File "C:\Users\oefel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 559, in __init__

self.add_url_rule(
  File "C:\Users\oefel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 67, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\oefel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1217, in add_url_rule
    self.url_map.add(rule)
  File "C:\Users\oefel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 1388, in 
add
    rule.bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\oefel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 730, in bind
    self.compile()
  File "C:\Users\oefel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 794, in compile
    self._build = self._compile_builder(False).__get__(self, None)
  File "C:\Users\oefel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 951, in _compile_builder
    code = compile(module, "<werkzeug routing>", "exec")
TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module"
```

in running a Dash app. This is my code:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_renderer
import dash_html_components as html  # div_tags
import dash_core_components as dcc  # graphs
import plotly

app = dash.Dash()
colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}
app.layout = html.Div(style={'backgroundColor': colors['background']}, children=[
    html.H1(
        children='Hello Dash',
        style={
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'color': colors['text']
        }
    ),
    html.Div(children='Dash: A web application framework for Python.', style={
        'textAlign': 'center',
        'color': colors['text']
    }),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='Graph1',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'plot_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                'paper_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                'font': {
                    'color': colors['text']
                }
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

I've done some searching and found nothing that would indicate what this error would mean. Would anyone be able to provide any insight? Thank you!

Comment: I'm running the exact same code and I'm getting a proper output, that means there's no problem with code. Maybe there's a problem with dependency error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your version of Werkzeug to be Python 3.8 compatible.

Comment: That was the issue. It's working now, thank you so much!